# How to get the id of call log button of the phone?

Tags: android

How to get the id of call log button of the phone, to check whether its clicked or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [onKeyDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) or [onKeyUp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyUp%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) methods of [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class to get the keyCode of pressed key.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    // Your logic here.

    return false;
}
```